# Merge GeoServers

Tags: geoserver

I have 3 GeoServers with different configuration.

Is it possible to merge easily the 3 configurations in just one GeoServer, in order to make a more effective use of resources (RAM) and simplifying administration?

Comment: I guess not. If the number of layers/stores is not too high, you can transfer them manually. If there are a lot of layers, you could consider automating some transfer using the GeoServer REST API.

Comment: Yes the number of data is very high.
GeoServer REST API: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to do this, you can't just copy the workspaces etc as the configuration doesn't work that way.

The "best" way would be to download the data sets and upload them to the new server, it's possible that you could construct a python script with OGR to fetch the data as GML via WFS and then use the REST API to load the data into the new GeoServer but it would be messy. It's probably easier just to reload the layers you need from the original data.

Comment: There are somewhat hacky ways to make part of it work though. If one workspace is fully self-contained, that is, styles and layer groups are all local to it, layers are not referencing global system variables, then copying it around will mostly work. Mostly, as the tile cache configurations for the layers will be lost (they are in the global gwc folder, using the layer id as the file name... that part could be scripted though, thankfully the ids are UUIDs).